# Is grounding 12v 100W solar panel to a lightning rod necessary?

Tags: solar-cell, grounding, solar-charge-controller

My plan is to put a solar panel on my greenhouse to run a 150 W 12 V heater for 20 minutes max and turned on depending the low temperature is detected by a sensor, automation controller and a grow light for winter. My solar will have a Renology 20 A MPPT hooked to a 12 V 50 Ah lead battery. I am concerned about possible damage in case of a lightning strike near the system.

Just wondering if this low power will require grounding to a lightning rod to direct the high current from a  lightning strike to ground. In addition I live in canada were thunder is not very often as I live snow for 5 months, but in summer there are some thunderstorm.

Comment: Though it's difficult to protect against *direct* lightning strikes, as you say, I certainly would ground the system and add a lightning rod. Not only would it help protect the photovoltaic system, it could help protect greenhouse, too. Cheap and easy insurance.

Comment: Just a note, but 50 Ah will run that heater for four hours max but will flatten the battery. You probably want to plan on 2.5 h in use to prolong the life of the battery

Comment: @Transistor the heater will run generally 20 minutes depends on the temperature inside the greenhouse.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik My house has already has a lightning rod installed, would it be ok to install into it so no longer need to install another lightning rod? Or there will be a problem with these installation?

Comment: How close together are the buildings? Unless they're adjacent, I'd use a separate ground and lightning rod. Material cost should not increase by more than a few US dollars, and induced currents would be reduced, in the event of a strike nearby.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik at lease 20 feet apart.